# JavaScript not working in Wordpress 3.4.2

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have never tried to use javascript in wordpress post before.  Today, when I tried it does not work.  I tried several scripts, and none work.

For example,`<Script type="text/javascript"> alert("test");</script>`

In the past, I have  tried to use SweetCaptcha, and it did not work.  I am thinking this may also have to do this issue.

Has anyone had a similar situation?

I have disabled ALL plugins just to ensure there are no conflicts with them.

Comment: Isn't that just missing double quotes? <script type="text/javascript">alert("test");</script>

Comment: That snippet won't work because there's no `"` after `javascript`. Whether that's the general problem is hard to say...

Comment: sorry, just a typo.  the error still holds for all javascript.  I tried several different scripts, and even some plugins that I know use javascript like jquery-ui widget, and none work

Comment: Did you paste this script in a text editor (Add New Post page)?

Comment: I wouldn't use it at all anymore: https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/06/sweetcaptcha-service-used-to-distribute-adware.html

Answer (score 1):

I deactivated all plugins again, and activated them, and now it works.  I did this several times before, but I guess that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Remove all spaces from your code. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("test");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have never tried to use javascript in wordpress post before.

Javascript should work if pasted into the ***HTML*** version of the Post/Page editor. It *does not work* if pasted into the visual editor. If pasted into the visual editor the string will be encoded and won't work. I just tested it.